# Authenticating R Arrow With Temporary AWS Credentials in a Profile?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-arrow

I am trying to use the [arrow R package](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/index.html) to [read a parquet file from s3](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/fs.html).  The documentation only describes how to specifying `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` when authenticating for access to private s3 bucket.

However, I have to generate keys using okta which additionally provides `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` & `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` values as part of my profile.

**How can arrow in R be instructed to use the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` value and `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` value as part of authentication?  Or, how can arrow in R be instructed to use a profile instead?**

I have tried setting environment variables:

```
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="...", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="...", AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="...", AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN="...")

library("arrow")

read_parquet("s3://bucket/file.extension?region=us-east-1")
```

But this results in

> AWS Error [code 15]: No response body.

if I try to set the environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` then the same error occurs.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Hmm, I know it picks up credentials from `~/.aws/credentials`, and the aws-sdk-cpp (which arrow uses) also supports picking up credentials from these env vars: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/bb1fdce01cc7e8ae2fe7162f24c8836e9d3ab0a2/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h#L128. Could you report an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW?